# Search Icon not in center

Tags: antd

I am using search icon button from antd [See Example 2 From the Website](https://ant.design/components/button/), or you can see the code from here as well:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import { Button, Tooltip } from 'antd';
import { SearchOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
ReactDOM.render(
  <>
    <Tooltip title="search">
      <Button type="primary" shape="circle" icon={<SearchOutlined />} />
    </Tooltip>
  </>,
 document.getElementById('container'),
);
```

I have used the exact same code, but in my output, the search icon is not in the center, rather it is on the left.
Why is this so?

Comment: Could you reproduce this problem in a Codepen or Code Sandbox and share the link?

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue as you. I resolved this by overwrite the default CSS. You can add the following in your App.css

```
.anticon svg {
    display: block;
}
```

Let me know if this helps.